# Do we need "Help" Tag?

Tags: discussion

Do we need a tag named "Help" ??. I just saw in our SharePoint Stack exchange, in which 30+ SharePoint technical questions being tagged with "Help" tag, How does it going to help our SharePoint related questions ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it were used correctly.  The first two questions to use this tag, which would also indicate the intent of the creator of the tag, are about editing or providing help within SharePoint as part of their solution.

The Tag Info text now reads "Do Not use this tag to ask for help! Use this tag to indicate questions related to adding, providing, or modifying help resources or end user directions through SharePoint or SharePoint hosted solutions."

I have removed the tag from questions where it was used incorrectly. I think if you [look at what remains](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help), it should be more evident what the purpose of the tag is.

Comment: But all the questions asked here is for help, everybody knew it, then why do we need a tag to specify it.

Comment: While many questions have incorrectly used it that way, my point is the tag was meant to signify that the question was about building or constructing some sort of help functionality.  See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131267/sharepoint-2010-help-icon-search-is-broken about the "SharePoint Help Icon", and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132251/adding-help-tooltips-to-sharepoint-aspx-form-fields that is asking how to add "Help Tooltips" to custom form fields.  I propose the tag should be removed from the questions that did not mean it this way.

Comment: If that points to "SharePoint Help Icon" functionalities, then can we assign a name relevant to it ?

Comment: I removed the tag from questions that used it inappropriately, I think if you look at [what is left now](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help), the intent becomes more clear.